# What does the word "also" indicate in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

"It is also my favorite quotation. "

Does this sentence mean that this is my favorite quotation in addition to other quotations which are my favorites, or does it mean that I am a person who has this quotation as a favorite, in addition to the persons who have this quotation as a favorite?

Does "also" indicate the presence of more (favorite) quotations, or more persons who have this quotation as a favorite?

If it is the former, how what is the correct way express the later?

I mean if a person says, "This is my favorite quotation", how should I express that I also have it in the list of my favorites? Should I say, "It is also my favorite."? I want it to be more formal than "Mine too".

**A side question which arose while asking the question above:**

Is the following sentence correct from the perspective of punctuation?

I mean if a person says, "This is my favorite quotation", how should I express that I also have it in the list of my favorites?

Comment: You're not comparing like with like. Your *Mine too* (often just *Me too*) is only "informal" because you've discarded other words that would have made a "standard" SOV utterance. Go for *It is my favorite too*, then you won't have to worry about whether ***also*** attaches to ***is*** or ***my***. Note that *It is too my favorite* is "childish" phrasing implying emphatic refutation of someone else's assertion that it's actually *not* your favourite.

Comment: It could be either. You need to give a previous sentence (This is my father's favorite quotation. // This is a quotation which addresses the immigration problem. // This is a good example of a compound sentence. // ... )

Comment: Good question. _Also_ has a focus, and, like _only_, can occur before its focus (which could be _my_ or _my favorite quotation_); in this case, right after the first auxiliary verb, immediately before  _my favorite quotation_, which contains _my_. So it's irredeemably ambiguous in print; in speech, of course, one would stress _my_ if it were the focus, and no one would ever notice the potential ambiguity. Most sentences in English are multiply ambiguous in print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot to digest here. "It is also my favorite quotation" could refer to both instances (depending on context), i.e. more than one person has one quotation as their favorite ***or*** one person has two favorite quotations (though the latter could be argued to be contradictory since you could only have one favorite). Nonetheless, if speaking to a person, you could assume both.

You could alter the order of the sentence to make it known that there is only one quotation to be discussed.

> The quotation is my favorite also.